# How can I retrieve document from mongodb base using mongoose on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to find any information about retrieving data from mongodb, but everyone showing how to do that with new Models, not one that already created. How can I do that ?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/acme", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
    console.log("WERE CONNECTED");
});

mongoose.model("posts", { title: String });

const post = mongoose.model("posts").find({ title: "Post One" });
console.log("post", post);
```

[compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbGyv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` method returns `promise` and accepts `callback` as well

2 ways to retrieve `documents`

Using `callback`

```js
    const Post = mongoose.model("posts", { title: String });

    Post.find({ title: "Post One" },(err,result) => {
    // ...your result
    })
```

Using `async` `await`

```js
    const Post = mongoose.model("posts", { title: String });

    const find = async() => {
        const post = await Post.find({ title: "Post One" })
        console.log("post:",post)
    }
    find();
```

You can use `findOne()` if require only 1st document

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.find` as a promise to model,

```
const post = mongoose.model("posts", { title: String });
async function findMethod(){
    console.log("post", await post.find({ title: "Post One" }))
}
findMethod();
```